# docker и логи: Как лучше?

Tags: linux, логирование, docker

Больная тема передачи логов из контейнера в host-систему. Примерно год назад я уже задавал подобный вопрос как на docker-форуме, так и тут, никто ничего путёвого не посоветовал, может сейчас повезёт?

**Вопрос**: Как в realtime передавать логи, вывод stderr/out, etc из контейнера в host-систему rsyslog'у ?

Сейчас я использую `--log-driver=syslog --log-opt tag="{{.Name}}"` но в контейнере нет syslog'а и отдаётся только то, что в stdout/err и, что самое ужасное, не в realtime, а после завершения скрипта в контейнере.

Comment: docker logs [OPTIONS] CONTAINER
В опциях есть -f выводит в реал тайм
Знаю что в архистраторе , runcher есть вывод логов через socket.io в бараузер реал тайм .
Мы лично на нашем проекти используем RabbitMQ + kibana для логов.

Comment: Нормас варик, только проблема в том, что в моих контейнерах скрипты перловые которые по крону запускаются. Запустился контейнер, отработал - всё gg wp, нет его больше, и логов тоже нет.

Comment: Извиняюсь за отсутсвие праздники , всеже. 
Ваш варинт еще запись логов в файл и дописать пару строк в конце кода , чтоб он выгружал его куда-то, у нас кроном раз в день заходит на контенер с базой создает дамп , и выгружает на `Amazon S3` это дело , вы можете сделать также , причем что там триал до 5гб. Сами логи не много жрут . Или же поднять Как в нашем случае лог сервер .